# Find all foreign key of a table that prevent insert into it in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database with about 200 tables with many foreign keys constraints. There is no data in the database and I need to insert rows into a specified table `X`.

Because of the many foreign keys I don't know the order of how to insert in other tables so that I can insert into table `X`. Some of foreign key constraint are hierarchical.

How can I find out the order of inserting so that I can successfully insert data into table `X`? Is there any SQL query that help me?

**Edited**
I want result in a table with column "TableName" ,"ParentTableDependece" that show tree view and can get select from it

Comment: Look at "Table X's" dependencies in SQL Server Management Studio, and look at "objects which depend on this".

Comment: Yeah..you're capitalize every world in the sentences but not in question's title..:)

Comment: Right click on Table and then click View dependencies

Comment: Very nice. can i have a query that get table name and give all dependence?

Comment: This sounds like a naming/documentation issue more than anything - if its not obvious what the dependencies are, what are you actually going to insert into the other tables? Random data just so you can satisfy the FK constraints?

Answer (score 2):

Using this snippet, you can find all other tables and the foreign keys involved that reference your own table `X`:

```
;WITH ReferencingFK AS 
(
    SELECT 
        fk.Name AS 'FKName',
        OBJECT_NAME(fk.parent_object_id) 'ParentTable',
        cpa.name 'ParentColumnName',
        OBJECT_NAME(fk.referenced_object_id) 'ReferencedTable',
        cref.name 'ReferencedColumnName'
    FROM 
        sys.foreign_keys fk
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.columns cpa ON fkc.parent_object_id = cpa.object_id AND fkc.parent_column_id = cpa.column_id
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.columns cref ON fkc.referenced_object_id = cref.object_id AND fkc.referenced_column_id = cref.column_id
)
SELECT 
    FKName,
    ParentTable,
    ParentColumnName,
    ReferencedTable,
    ReferencedColumnName
FROM 
    ReferencingFK
WHERE
    ReferencedTable = 'X'   --  <=== put your table name here!
ORDER BY 
    ParentTable, ReferencedTable, FKName
```

Once you have all the tables that reference `X`, you might also need to repeat this for other tables (if they in turn depend on foreign key references)

Comment: I run this query but no result return

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
EXEC sp_help 'TableName'
```

This will give you the whole details of the table i.e you can get the relations, indexes and other information related with the object you pass with it.

Comment: Hi, Iswanto San, Can you please specify, what you have edited in the above answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not this?

```
EXEC sp_msdependencies @objname = 'X'
```

Raj

Comment: How do you mean? The column oSequence in the output should tell you the level of relationship.

Comment: I want result in a **table** with column "TableName" ,"ParentTableDependece" that show tree view  and can get select from it